# How to convert pdf to xml using pdfbox or any other library?

Tags: pdfbox, simple-xml-converter

I want to convert pdf files into xml. Is there any java library available that can be used for this?

Comment: Pdf2dom can do that, but not very well.

Comment: What do you expect the output to be? That being asked, library recommendations nowadays are off topic on stack overflow.

Answer (score 1):

You can fetch xml representation of any PDF document as below using **[Apache Tika](https://tika.apache.org/)** library

```
InputStream stream = new FileInputStream("sample.pdf");
ContentHandler handler = new ToXMLContentHandler();
Metadata metadata = new Metadata();
AutoDetectParser parser = new AutoDetectParser();
System.out.println(parser.parse(stream, handler, metadata));
```